# IconNavigationPage with Prism MasterPage

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

Im working on a xamarin forms Project. Im using **iconize** nuget for my icons. To use icons in bar i must use **IconNavigationPage**. Now i want to use the **IconNavigationPage** with my Prism Masterpage..

I checked, **IconNavigationPage** inherits from **Navigationpage**, so i created a new NavigationPage from PrismTemplate, and i Edited to inherits to from IconNavigation.

This is what i did

```
<IconNavigationPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
            prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
            x:Class="Fixmyplacemobileapp.Views.MyNavigation">
```

Add i get this error

```
 'IconNavigationPage' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

i have the nuget installed where do i reference it.

Answer (score 2):

The error should tell you what you're doing wrong. You're trying to reference a Type that does not exist in the Xamarin.Forms namespace. You may notice in your App.xaml there is a namespace declaration for Prism so that it can then reference PrismApplication. You must do this same sort of thing to reference the correct namespace/assembly for the IconNavigationPage.

That said you shouldn't need it. You should be able to simply register IconNavigationPage (& in Prism 7.0 IconTabbedPage) for Navigation. I suggest you take a look at this [example](https://github.com/SDXamarinDevs/October-2017-AdMob/tree/master/starter/MakinMoney/src/MakinMoney) from the San Diego Xamarin Meetup which includes samples of the IconPages and the use of the MasterDetailPage, TabbedPage and NavigationPage with Prism

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change your code behind for the page :

using Xamarin.Forms;

```
namespace Fixmyplacemobileapp.Views
{
    public partial class MainPage : IconNavigationPage
    {
        public MyNavigation()
        {
```

The Important part is **public partial class MyNavigation : IconNavigationPage**

Make sure you also add the nuget in your pcl, android and ios projects

Comment: Its not necessary to change the page class, what is needed is to register IconNavigationPage `containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<IconNavigationPage>(nameof(NavigationPage));` im using Prism